# Nrpe Not pulling date NRPE: Unable to read output

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios, custom-component, nrpe

I'm trying to get memory metric from client machine. I installed nrpe in client machine and works well for default checks like load, users and all.

Manual output from client machine,

```
root@Nginx:~# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mem -w 50 -c 40 
OK - 7199 MB (96%) Free Memory
```

But when i try from server, other metrics works but memory metrics not working,

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-179 ~]$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 107.XX.XX.XX -c check_mem 
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

Other metrics works well

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-179 ~]$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 107.XX.XX.XX -c check_load
OK - load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05|load1=0.000;15.000;30.000;0; load5=0.010;10.000;25.000;0; load15=0.050;5.000;20.000;0;
```

I ensured that check_mem command has execution permission for all,

```
root@Nginx:~# ll /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mem 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2394 Sep 6 00:00 /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mem*
```

Also here is my client side nrpe config commands

```
command[check_users]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_users -w 5 -c 10 
command[check_load]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20 
command[check_disk]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/sda1 
command[check_zombie_procs]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -w 5 -c 10 -s Z 
command[check_procs]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -w 200 -c 250 
command[check_http]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -I 127.0.0.1 
command[check_swap]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_swap -w 30 -c 20 
command[check_mem]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mem -w 30 -c 20
```

Can anyone help me to fix the issue?

Comment: Check your log for NRPE deamon. `/var/log/messages` or `journactl`...

Comment: You manually run the `check_mem` as **root** user, but `nrpe` checks are run as **nagios** user, which has not full privileges.

Comment: Have you added recently that line `command[check_mem]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mem -w 30 -c 20` into the `nrpe.cfg` file? If `nrpe` is run as a daemon, have you remembered to restart it?

Comment: My client machine is ubuntu 16.04.. @Jdamian I restarted the service, even after reboot the machine it does not work... check_mem command can be executed by any users... I could not get what is the issue :(

Comment: Then, configure NRPE in debug mode with a log file, restart, try to run the `check_nrpe -c check_mem` and post the lines found in the log file.

Comment: @Jdamian This is from log \n    Sep 17 10:18:06 Nginx nrpe[8549]: Handling the connection...
    Sep 17 10:18:06 Nginx nrpe[8549]: Host is asking for command 'check_mem' to be run...
    Sep 17 10:18:06 Nginx nrpe[8549]: Running command: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mem -w 30 -c 20
    Sep 17 10:18:06 Nginx nrpe[8549]: Command completed with return code 0 and output:
    Sep 17 10:18:06 Nginx nrpe[8549]: Return Code: 0, Output: NRPE: Unable to read output
    Sep 17 10:18:06 Nginx nrpe[8549]: Connection from  closed.

Comment: @Jdamian Issue is fixed. My script was having problem.. After i changed to different plugin it works...